# Solving simple transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to solve

```
Tan[x] == 1/x
```

Solve[] does not work, suggesting that there is no nice analytical solution for x.

Surprisingly, NSolve[] does not work either:

```
NSolve[Tan[x] == 1/x, x, Reals]
```

returns: 'This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve'

However, plotting these two functions shows that they cross around x=0.86:
[image: Crossing of Tan(x) and 1/x]

This looks suspiciously close to Cos[Pi/6] = 0.866025 but it isn't. It's about 0.86028 (obtained by expanding the graph).

Am I missing something really obvious??

Thanks

Comment: Use `FindRoot`.

Comment: There are infinitely many roots, so you need to specify the one you want: `Solve[{Tan[x] == 1/x, 0 < x < 1}, x]`. Alternatively, using `cotSol[]` from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89051): `N[cotSol[1], 20]`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Can Reduce *really* not solve for x here?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here). However if it doesn't enlighten you, take a look at [Roots of a characteristic equation. Can Mathematica solve it?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109583/roots-of-a-characteristic-equation-can-mathematica-solve-it/109626#109626).

Comment: As J.M. mentioned, there are many roots. So if you `Reduce` it to the area between two singularities: `Reduce[Tan[x] == 1/x && 0 < x < Pi/2, Reals]`, you get a pure function `x == Root[{-1 + #1 Tan[#1] &, 0.86033358901937976248}]`

Comment: Duh, yes I see. Tan(x) will cross 1/x lots of places, of course. Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of finding the intersection, you can also look for the root of Tan[x]-1/x, which yields the desired result

```
FindRoot[Tan[x] - 1/x == 0, {x, 0.5}]
{x -> 0.860334}
```

Greetings,
Jürgen

Comment: Right! Yes it works, thank you. I had forgotten about that function :)

Answer (score 5):

`NSolve` is primarily meant for polynomial equations, or equations that can be transformed into a polynomial.

For equations like this, we usually have two choices:

- `FindRoot` to find a *single* solution numerically, based on a starting guess
- `Reduce` can often find an "exact" solution (in some sense), but to succeed it typically requires specifying an interval in which to look.

This equation has an infinite number of real solutions.

```
Plot[{Tan[x], 1/x}, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}]
```

[image]

Use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) to find one:

```
FindRoot[Tan[x] == 1/x, {x, 1}]
(* {x -> 0.860334} *)
```

Use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) to find *all solutions* in a given interval:

```
Reduce[Tan[x] == 1/x && -2 Pi < x < 2 Pi, x, Reals]

(* x == Root[{-1 + #1 Tan[#1] &, -3.4256184594817281465}] || 
 x == Root[{-1 + #1 Tan[#1] &, -0.86033358901937976248}] || 
 x == Root[{-1 + #1 Tan[#1] &, 0.86033358901937976248}] || 
 x == Root[{-1 + #1 Tan[#1] &, 3.4256184594817281465}] *)
```

Note that `Reduce[Tan[x] == 1/x, x, Reals]` does not return any solution.  Specifying the interval was essential.

This latter solution is exact in the following sense:

- When `Reduce` succeeds, it is guaranteed to find *all* solutions in the given interval
- The [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects, while based on a numerical approximation, represent an exact solution, and can be used as any other exact number in Mathematica (e.g. can be computed to arbitrary precision).

This interesting and useful feature of `Reduce` is discussed in [this Wolfram Blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/).